# Segmentation Fault 11, Xcode 8.2.1, Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to create an archive of my application, but I'm getting a segmentation fault when building for an iOS Device. I do not encounter this issue when building for the simulator. So far, I have:

- Cleaned my project
- Cleaned my build folder
- Deleted my derived data folder
- Installed Mac OS Sierra
- Installed additional Xcode tools after updating to Sierra
- Restarted Xcode/computer multiple times

The error typically looks like this:

```
Call parameter type does not match function signature!
0  swift                    0x000000010f4ab3ad PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 45
1  swift                    0x000000010f4aab56 SignalHandler(int) + 790
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fffb1b28bba _sigtramp + 26
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x000000011033a000 _sigtramp + 1585517664
4  swift                    0x000000010f3038e8 llvm::TypeFinder::incorporateValue(llvm::Value const*) + 296
5  swift                    0x000000010f3032fa llvm::TypeFinder::run(llvm::Module const&, bool) + 682
6  swift                    0x000000010f1c827e (anonymous namespace)::TypePrinting::incorporateTypes(llvm::Module const&) + 30
7  swift                    0x000000010f1c9bdb printAsOperandImpl(llvm::Value const&, llvm::raw_ostream&, bool, llvm::ModuleSlotTracker&) + 171
8  swift                    0x000000010f30c633 (anonymous namespace)::VerifierSupport::Write(llvm::Value const*) + 67
9  swift                    0x000000010f31616e (anonymous namespace)::Verifier::VerifyCallSite(llvm::CallSite) + 590
10 swift                    0x000000010f318ef3 (anonymous namespace)::Verifier::visitCallInst(llvm::CallInst&) + 35
11 swift                    0x000000010f329ac1 (anonymous namespace)::VerifierLegacyPass::runOnFunction(llvm::Function&) + 1649
12 swift                    0x000000010f2e089d llvm::FPPassManager::runOnFunction(llvm::Function&) + 973
13 swift                    0x000000010f2e02ab llvm::FPPassManager::runOnModule(llvm::Module&) + 43
14 swift                    0x000000010f2e977a llvm::legacy::PassManager::run(llvm::Module&) + 1514
15 swift                    0x000000010c605901 performLLVM(swift::IRGenOptions&, swift::DiagnosticEngine&, llvm::sys::SmartMutex<false>*, llvm::GlobalVariable*, llvm::Module*, llvm::TargetMachine*, llvm::StringRef) + 5921
16 swift                    0x000000010c6038c1 performIRGeneration(swift::IRGenOptions&, swift::ModuleDecl*, swift::SILModule*, llvm::StringRef, llvm::LLVMContext&, swift::SourceFile*, unsigned int) + 2625
17 swift                    0x000000010c4b8f31 performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 23777
18 swift                    0x000000010c4b12b3 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 17859
19 swift                    0x000000010c46d5cf main + 8239
20 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fffb191b255 start + 1
```

In the stack dump, there's this line:

```
2.  Running pass 'Module Verifier' on function '@_TZFC12MyAppName23MyClassNameg13nextImagePathV10Foundation3URL'
```

I think this indicates the error is being thrown when compiling the static computed variable `nextImagePath`, which returns a `URL` to a file path. Internally, this relies on a few other computed variables and a method `nextFilePathForDirectoryAtURL`. Altogether, the code looks like this:

```
/* 
 * This is the offending computed variable.
 */

static var nextImagePath: URL {
  return nextFilePathForDirectoryAtURL(imageDirectory, withExtension: "jpg");
}

/*
 * The method called by above variable. It looks through all the
 * files in a directory, finds the one with the highest index,
 * and returns a new path by incrementing the highest index by 1.
 */

fileprivate static func nextFilePathForDirectoryAtURL(_ url: URL, withExtension ext: String) -> URL {
  guard let files = try? FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(
    at: url,
    includingPropertiesForKeys: nil,
    options: .skipsHiddenFiles) else {
      fatalError("Could not create next file path for directory at url: \(url)");
  }

  var maxFileNumber = 0;
  for file in files {
    let fileName = file.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent;

    guard
      let fileNumber = Int(fileName),
      file.pathExtension.lowercased() == ext.lowercased()
      else { continue }

    maxFileNumber = max(maxFileNumber, fileNumber);
  }

  return url.appendingPathComponent("\(maxFileNumber + 1).\(ext)");
}

/*
 * Some supporting computed variables for constructing directories.
 */

fileprivate static var libraryDirectory: URL {
  guard let url = try? FileManager.default.url(
    for: .libraryDirectory,
    in: .userDomainMask,
    appropriateFor: nil,
    create: true) else {
      fatalError("Could not create library directory url.");
  }

  return url;
}

fileprivate static var documentSetDirectory: URL {
  let directory = libraryDirectory.appendingPathComponent("MemberDocumentSets");

  try? FileManager.default.createDirectory(
    at: directory,
    withIntermediateDirectories: true,
    attributes: nil);

  return directory;
}

fileprivate static var imageDirectory: URL {
  let directory = documentSetDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Images");

  try? FileManager.default.createDirectory(
    at: directory,
    withIntermediateDirectories: true,
    attributes: nil);

  return directory;
}
```

I'm not really sure why this error is occurring, or why it doesn't happen when building for the simulator. I've been trying to find answers for about 5 hours now with no luck, so I'd thought post. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp, after many hours, I was able to deduce that the error was caused by the `documentSetDirectory` computed variable. Apparently, the compiler was not happy about converting the result of a `try` statement into an optional. Instead, I had to wrap the statement in a `do catch` block. The following code fixed my problem:

```
fileprivate static var documentSetDirectory: URL {
  let directory = libraryDirectory.appendingPathComponent("MemberDocumentSets");

  do {
    try FileManager.default.createDirectory(
      at: directory,
      withIntermediateDirectories: true,
      attributes: nil);
  } catch {

    /* 
     * Do nothing. So why have a catch block at all? Because: for some reason
     * this prevents the compiler from spitting up. Apparently it didn't like
     * converting the `try` to an optional here. Weirdly, I'm still doing the
     * optional conversion elsewhere in this same class without issue (see
     * computed variables below).
     *
     * ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
     */
  }

  return directory;
}

fileprivate static var imageDirectory: URL {
  let directory = documentSetDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Images");

  try? FileManager.default.createDirectory(
    at: directory,
    withIntermediateDirectories: true,
    attributes: nil);

  return directory;
}
```

Evidently, this must be a bug with the compiler. I created an empty project and copied the original code, but it compiled without issue and I was unable to find any project setting differences that caused the same error. In any case, I'm glad to have found a solution, and hopefully it'll save some time for a few poor souls in the future.